# Java call setter in constructor

Tags: java, constructor, setter

I am validating input data in setter method and don't want to validate it again in constructor. I wonder if calling the setter in the constructor is good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can call setter in constructor.

```
Sample() {
    setName("name");
}
```

it's not prohibited

Answer (score 4):

Calling a setter from a constructor works just fine. Promotes code reuse.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that. It's possible, but I would also suggest you to check forum  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893558/calling-setters-from-a-constructor).

This post should give you idea about Construtor Injection vs Setter Injection [link](http://misko.hevery.com/2009/02/19/constructor-injection-vs-setter-injection/)

Answer (score 1):

Generally considered safe, with the following caveat:

the only possible trouble you can get into is if the setter (or any method you call from a constructor) is overridden in a sub class. To be absolutely safe (paranoic?), make sure that all methods called from a constructor are final.