# Is validating fields in both constructor and setter considered bad redundant code?

Tags: java, coding-style, getter-setter

I have the following class :

```
public class Project {

    private int id;
    private String name;  

    public Project(int id, String name) {
        if(name == null ){
            throw new NullPointerException("Name can't be null");
        }

        if(id == 0 ){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("id can't be zero");
        }

            this.name = name;
            this.id = id;

    }

    private Project(){}

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) { 
        if(id == 0 ){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("id can't be zero");
        }
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName()
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        if(name == null ){
            throw new NullPointerException("Name can't be null");
        }
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

If you noticed that setName and setId share the same validation for its fields with the constructor. Is this redundant code that could cause issues in the future ( for example if somebody edit the the setter to allow 0 for the id and prevent -1 instead but didn't change the constructor) ? . Should I use a private method to do the check and share it between the constructor and the setter which seems too much if there's a lot of fields.

Note: This is why im not using the setters in the constructor. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4893604/302707

Comment: Use setters in CTORs if you are worried.

Comment: Or (in case a setter cannot be called from Constructor), pass the validation logic to a shared, private method.

Comment: what's with the `private` constructor and validation in the getter?

Comment: @Captain Giraffe: This is why im not using the setter http://stackoverflow.com/a/4893604/302707

Comment: @Jimmy I saw that. Still, my comment remains.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question but you should use `if(id <= 0)` instead of `if(id == 0)`. i can see no point of having id as a negative value if the 0 is not valid unless there is a special reason to it.

Comment: @Captain Giraffe: So what if someone override the setter without adding the validation (setters are not final) then projects subclass objects will not be valid.

Comment: @Jimmy With overriding comes responsibility. Take the calls to super in a large amount of the Android API for instance.

Comment: Can you provide an example (maybe from the Android source code?), I'm an Android app developer myself and i'd love to be proven wrong.

Comment: @Jimmy, if you are an Android developer you are plenty aware of all the super calls in an Activity for instance.

Comment: How is this relevant, the Activity has only one default constructor (they dont use setter their).

Answer (score 2):

Here is the revised code:

```
public class Project {

    private int id;
    private String name;  

    public Project(int id, String name, Date creationDate, int fps, List<String> frames) {

        checkId(id);
            checkName(name);
            //Insted of lines above you can call setters too.

            this.name = name;
            this.id = id;

    }

    private Project(){}

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) { 
        checkId(id);
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName()
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
            checkName(name);
        this.name = name;
    }

    private void checkId(int id){
       if(id == 0 ){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("id can't be zero");
        }
    }

    private void checkName(String name){
            if(name == null ){
            throw new NullPointerException("Name can't be null");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: While a solution, it still does not address OPs concerns.

Comment: this is a trade off and depends on the developer requirement. depends on the way that they maintain their code.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you should define one method per field as `isValid()` and then call the same method in you setter as well as Constructor.

Comment: But how do you think isValid could work for both id and name.

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes. Rather than that, just call the setters from your constructor:

```
public Project(int id, String name, Date creationDate, int fps, List<String> frames) {
    setName(name);
    setId(id);
    // other stuff with creationDate, fps and frames?
}
```

Also, you shouldn't check for a null `name` in `getName` -- do it in `setName`. Otherwise, bugs are going to be hard to track down -- you want to catch the invalid name as soon as it comes in, not when it's used (which may be much later).

Comment: IMHO, this is bad advice...unless you made the mutator methods `final`.

Comment: bad because if someone overrides `setName` and `setId` it could be catastrophe. it is not recommended to call non-private or non-final method in the constructor within the same class

Comment: Good catch to both; you should make the mutator methods (or the whole class) `final` if you go with this approach. Of course, if you go with an approach like `isValid(String)` or `checkName(String)`, the same condition applies.

Answer (score 0):

if you make `Project` immutable, it will eliminate the redundant code. but for now, i think explicitly throwing exceptions in both the constructor and mutator methods is fine.

and i would not call the mutator methods within the constructor for many reasons, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404301/whats-wrong-with-overridable-method-calls-in-constructors). also, i would remove the validation code in the accessor method...it's not necessary.