# Need Clarity on Java constructors

Tags: java

Okay am just beginning to learn Java and I have a doubt regarding constructors.

isn't constructor just another method with same name as class?? If so Why do we need it? Cant we just use methods?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Purpose of a constructor in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19941825/purpose-of-a-constructor-in-java)

Comment: Constructor is used to initialize your instance variable . Suppose if create an object then default constructor automatically initialize u value whereas if u create method then u have to call that method every time u create a new object .

Comment: Isn't faster to just Google? http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076204/core-java/understanding-constructors.html

Comment: A constructor actually makes the object. You can't use any methods (other than static methods) until you have created an object. Are you using any objects yet? (Created using the `new` keyword)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Constructors have no return type.
2. They are used for instantiating a class.
3. They can be called from subclass using Super keyword.
4. Their name must be same as it's classname

Answer (score 0):

Constructors are called on object creation. You can initialize stuff in other methods of course but then you'd have to call them explicitly.

You don't need to write a constructor. But if you want to do things to ready your object, you put in in your constructor.