# Is constructor the only way to create the object of a class in JAVA?

Tags: java, object, constructor

If a constructor is the only way to create the object of a class then how
String name = "Java";
is able to create an object of String class even without using constructor.

Comment: Please check this and see it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19941825/purpose-of-a-constructor-in-java

Comment: The compiler built one and put it in the .class constants pool.

Answer (score 8):

No. Constructor is not the only way.

There are at least two more ways:

1. [Clone the object](https://www.javatpoint.com/object-cloning)
2. [Serialize and then deserialize](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/serialization-in-java/amp/) object.

Though in case with your example - neither of these is used.

In this case Java uses [string pool](https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-pool)

Answer (score 1):

There is another way of creating objects via

- `Class.forName("fully.qualified.class.name.here").newInstance()`
- `Class.forName("fully.qualified.class.name.here").getConstuctor().newInstance()`

but they call constructor under the hood.

[Other ways](https://dzone.com/articles/5-different-ways-to-create-objects-in-java-with-ex) to create objects are cloning via `clone()` method and deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose in a loop-hole type of way you could use the class object too:

```
// Get the class object using an object you already have   
Class<?> clazz = object.getClass();

// or get class object using the type
Class<?> clazz = Object.class;

// Get the constructor object (give arguments 
// of Class objects of types if the constructor takes arguments)
Constructor<?> constructor = clazz.getConstructor();

// then invoke it (and pass arguments if need be)
Object o = constructor.newInstance();
```

I mean you still use the constructor so it probably doesn't really count. But hey, its there!

[Java doc link for Class object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html)

Answer (score -1):

YES, each time a new object is created, at least one constructor will be invoked.

Look at this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_object_classes.htm), this will explain all with objects, classes and constructors.

Comment: That is only correct for the "regular" ways. Neither cloning nor deserialization actually go through a constructor. They use Java black magic to bypass all of those mechanisms and they use mechanisms built directly into the language instead.