# Class name & Function name in Java

Tags: java, methods, constructor

I'm studying Swing in Java at first.
above thing is correct and another thing is incorrect code.

**Correct**

```
public class Example extends JFrame{
    public Example() {
    }
```

**Incorrect**

```
public class Example extends JFrame{
    public Othor() {
    }
```

Despite it's not Constructor, why function name should be same with class name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean with "Despite it's not Constructor" - in the first snippet, `public Example()` **is** a constructor, means it will be executed when the object is created with `new Example()`. In the second snippet, `public Othor()` would be a normal method of the class, even though it is missing the return type, so this does not compile (this is probably the error message you get, something like `Return type is missing`).
The correct code for the second snipped would be something like

```
public class Example extends JFrame{
    public void othor() {
    }
}
```

(note that methods usually start with a non-capital letter). In this case, a default constructor would implicitly be created, but `void othor()` is a normal method of the class.
Also note that this is just normal Java behaviour, and completely independant of Swing or any other toolkit or framework.

See also [Purpose of a constructor in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19941847/1611055)