# Okay To Call Private Final Method from Constructor?

Tags: java, constructor

I'm aware that you could call a method from a constructor, but it could lead to problems later on if the method could be overridden. The following code is just an example I've written demonstrating my issue:

Let say I have the following **subclass**:

```
private boolean isActive;

public ChargeGun(String gameObjectID, String gameObjectName, String desc, int numberofshots, int damage, boolean isActive) {
    super(gameObjectID, gameObjectName, desc, numberofshots, damage);

    setAttributes(isActive);

}

public ChargeGun(String gameObjectID, String gameObjectName, int numberofshots, int damage, boolean isActive) {
    super(gameObjectID, gameObjectName, numberofshots, damage);

    setAttributes(isActive);

}

private final void setAttributes(boolean isActive)
{
    this.isActive = isActive;
}
```

The `boolean isActive` is specific to `ChargeGun` and not any other gun. Given that I have two constructors in my subclass, rather than type `isActive = true` twice, could I call a `private final method` to do it? The reason is, if my attributes for ChargeGun grow, then I would have to add attributes in both constructors. If I do it with a private final method, everything is set in one place. Is this bad practice?

I can't chain the ChargeGun constructors because both call the super classes constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `private` method cannot be overriden, you do not also need to mark it `final` (which also means it cannot be overriden). Just one of `final` **or** `private` would be sufficient. However, the method needs to be modified slightly. Like,

```
private void setAttributes(boolean isActive)
{
    this.isActive = isActive;
}
```

your version **always** sets it to `true`. If that is *intentional* I would remove the setter entirely, and do something like

```
private final boolean isActive = true;
```

which is a *declaration* and *initialization* of an immutable field.

Comment: this method is useless, you should just inline it. Also note that the 2nd constructor is rather strange, because it ends to `this.isActive = this.isActive`

Comment: @Elliot, that was a mistake, your version is correct

Comment: @RC - Sorry but what do you mean inline it?

Comment: inline = remove it and put its' content where it's called

Comment: @RC - If my attributes for ChargeGun grow is using a private method bad practice?

Comment: I mean "as is" the private method is useless, it has 1 line and is called once (the other call is useless)

Comment: @Elliott Frisch - Just for reassurace, if my ChargeGun gets more attributes, calling a private setter is okay right, not bad practice?

Comment: @Nexusfactor It's fine. It really comes down to person preference. However, if you're looking for [best practices](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4893604/2970947)...

Answer (score 0):

If you need your setAttributes, it certainly means you have common variables to always set the same way in multiple constructors. Wouldn't it be more clear to have a "full constructor" which have all the assignment you make in setAttributes, and other shorter versions of your version calling the full version ?

Also, you really should consider using [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) which clearly deals with those object that can be constructed in many different ways. If you thing it is a lot of work, just know that some plugins for IDE such as [InnerBuilder](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7354?pr=idea) make it easy to generate. If you look at how languages evolve, you will see more and more builder-like api (Stream, Optional...).

Comment: The problem is that it's a subclass, so I can't chain them. They call the abstract constructors.